# Get the number of instance of a component in angular 2/4/6?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-directives

I want to get the number of occurrence of a component. Menas want to know how many times this particular component is rendering?

Actually, I have made a toaster and want to know how many times it's displaying?

My codes are:

**main.component.ts:**

```
      <toster-component [message]="'this is toster message'"   [type]="'danger'" [duration]="'15'"> </toster-component>
      <toster-component [message]="'this is toster message 2'" [type]="'info' 
  [duration]="'5'"> </toster-component>
```

**toster.component.ts:**

```
import { Component,Input,OnInit,ContentChildren,ElementRef,QueryList } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'toster-component',
  templateUrl: './toster.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./toster.component.css'],
});

export class TosterComponent implements OnInit {
  public isShow:any=true;
  public TabItem:any;

  @Input() message:string;  // Will show the message.
  @Input() type:string; // What type will decide the style of this toster.
  @Input() duration:number; // If duration ( In second ) is available the it will show till duration otherwise it will show permanently till manually closed 

  @ContentChildren(TosterComponent, {read: ElementRef}) tosterComponents:QueryList<TosterComponent>;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
       console.log("Length: ",this.tosterComponents.toArray().length);
     }


  ngOnInit(){
      this.message=this.message?this.message:'Test Message';
      this.type=this.type?this.type:'info';    

      if(this.duration>0){
          setTimeout(()=>{
            this.isShow=false;
          },this.duration*1000);
       } 
    } 


 }
```

**In the above code I am using below code:**

```
@ContentChildren(TosterComponent, {read: ElementRef}) tosterComponents:QueryList<TosterComponent>;

ngAfterContentInit() {
           console.log("Length: ",this.tosterComponents.toArray().length); // I want to print the instance of this component.
         }
```

to achieve the same, But its showing only **1**. But it should be **2** because its using 2 times in **main.component.ts**.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a `static` class variable, and increase its count everytime the `constructor()` runs.

I have prepared [THIS](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h8yna1) here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you handle your toaster, but when I did one and used one, I was using a service.

When you have a service, it is decorated with `@Injectable`, meaning it's a singleton.

And because of that, you can consider it as the only source of truth, and use it to store your toaster informations.

So, to answer your question : create a service that will create your toasters. When you display one, add 1 to the counter, and when it disappears, remove 1 from the counter.

Comment: @@trichetriche Thank you, But I think there should be a predefine decorator or something like that to count the occurrences of a component which is provided by angular itself. I don't want to make custom service.

Comment: Well there isn't, so you have to make one. And if you want one to be made, that's not a request you make on SOF, but on Angular's repo.